# Float Array to Byte Array and Vise Versa

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sockets, udp, byte

My ultimate goal is to be able to send an array of floats over a UDP socket, but for now I'm just trying to get a few things working in python3. 
The code below works just fine:

```
import struct
fake_data = struct.pack('f', 5.38976) 
print(fake_data) 
data1 = struct.unpack('f', fake_data) 
print(data1)
```

Output:

```
 b'\xeax\xac@'
(5.3897600173950195,)
```

But when I try this I get:

```
electrode_data = [1.22, -2.33, 3.44]

for i in range(3):
    data = struct.pack('!d', electrode_data[i])  # float -> bytes
    print(data[i])
    x = struct.unpack('!d', data[i])  # bytes -> float
    print(x[i])
```

Output:

```
63
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cbutton.py", line 18, in <module>
x = struct.unpack('!d', data[i])  # bytes -> float
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

How can I turn a float array to byte array and vise versa. The reason I'm tryin to accomplish this is because the first code allows me to send float data from a client to server (one by one) using a UDP socket. My ultimate goal is to do this with an array so I can plot the values using matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only packing a single float here. But then you're trying to pass the first byte of the resulting buffer (which was implicitly converted to `int`) to `unpack`. You need to give it the entire buffer. Also, to do this in a more general way, you want to first encode the number of items in your array as an integer.

```
import struct

electrode_data = [1.22, -2.33, 3.44]
# First encode the number of data items, then the actual items
data = struct.pack("!I" + "d" * len(electrode_data), len(electrode_data), *electrode_data)
print(data)

# Pull the number of encoded items (Note a tuple is returned!)
elen = struct.unpack_from("!I", data)[0]
# Now pull the array of items
e2 = struct.unpack_from("!" + "d" * elen, data, 4)
print(e2)
```

(The `*electrode_data` means to flatten the list: it's the same as `electrode_data[0], electrode_data[1]...`)

If you really only want to do one at a time:

```
for elem in electrode_data:
    data = struct.pack("!d", elem)
    print(data)
    # Again note that unpack *always* returns a tuple (even if only one member)
    d2 = struct.unpack("!d", data)[0]
    print(d2)
```